# Can't join my friends' world on Minecraft Pocket Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't connect to my friends' world on Minecraft Pocket Edition version 0.15.3. I can see their name pop up, I press it and it tries to load. Then it says: you need to authenticate to XBox Live. Please help!

Comment: Are you playing on the same WiFi? Did you try authenticating with Xbox Live?

Comment: Yes we are playing on the same wifi, they can connect to me but I cant connect to them?? I don't know how to authenticate to xbox live, I don't have an xbox live account?

Comment: @Jadthelad01 I have the same issue, and I couldn't solve it. Maybe someone will answer it :/

Answer (score 1):

Get Xbox app installed and log in the Minecraft then log in the Xbox app. I think this should remove the authentication problem. If you don't have an account then sign up. In the realms option you see "sign in" tap it. I assume that you already have email registered in your phone . Use that and sign up

Answer (score -1):

How to connect in Minecraft:

1. Turn on Hotspot on the host.
2. Connect a second phone to the other phone.
3. Open world (1st phone)
4. connect to world on second phone(right tab)

Comment: Hi Elijah!  Can you add some more information to this? What do you mean on 2. (Is the hotspot on the same phone running as host?) - Also, do you mean hotspot like cellular-wifi hotspot, or just allow other phones to connect to the first one in a network? (so that a hotspot could be like the same wifi?)